# How can I design an r function that selects specific elements from a list of lists, and returns a dataframe as an output

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to set up an r function that will select relevant elements from a list, and end up with a dataframe as output.

Here is the list I'm using:

```
test_list<-list(set1=list(2, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, 2), set2=list(4, 6, NA, NA, 2, 1, 1), set3=c(2, 3, 2, 1, NA, NA, NA))
```

For each element of my list, I'd like to keep only the sublists that contains less than 4 NA elements.

Here is the function I've built:

```
is.useful <-function(x){ #x is a list of sublists 
#I want to keep only the sublists with less than 4 NA elements
    vector <-c()
    for(i in x){
        if(sum(is.na(x[[i]])) <= 3){
        vector <-c(vector, unlist(x[[i]]))
        }
        }
    return (vector)
    }
```

Runing `is.useful(test_list)`, I'm getting the Error in x[[i]] : type 'list'

I don't understand the issue here because:
`sum(is.na(test_list[["set1"]]))` returns the right answer 4 and 
`unlist(test_list[["set1"]])` also gives me the sublist as a vector ( `is.vector(unlist(test_list[["set1"]]))` returns TRUE )

I've also tried something else, namely transforming the list of lists into a dataframe, using following command:

```
dd  <-  as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(test_list), nrow=length(unlist(test_list[1]))))
```

From there, I try to run a very similar function, without the unlist:

```
is.useful2 <-function(x){ #x is dataframe
#I want to keep only the vectors with less than 4 NA elements
    vector <-c()
    for(i in x){
        if(sum(is.na(x[i])) <= 3){
        vector <-c(vector, (x[i]))
        }
        }
    return (vector)
    }
```

`is.useful2(dd)` returns Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i) : undefined columns selected

**What do I expect?** In this specific example, I expect a dataframe of 2 vectors, set2 and set3, for which I have less than 4 NA values.

I'm a bit lost. What did I do wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm expecting to get a dataframe containing the 2 vectors that have less than 4 NA elements, namely set2 and set3.

Comment: What is the output that you expect to obtain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this helps:

```
 do.call(cbind,test_list[sapply(test_list,function(x)sum(is.na(unlist(x))))<4])
     set2 set3
[1,] 4    2   
[2,] 6    3   
[3,] NA   2   
[4,] NA   1   
[5,] 2    NA  
[6,] 1    NA  
[7,] 1    NA
```

Comment: It even works without the `unlist()`: `do.call(cbind,test_list[sapply(test_list,function(x)sum(is.na(x)))<4])` gives the same output

Comment: Really? Tht would would be nice.. I never thought of it in that direction

Comment: Could you tell me why my loop functions did not work, though ? It looks like they are somehow consistent with what I aim to do, but not with the format of my data.

Comment: Oh there are few reasons why your code did not run. First, You are using `for (i in x)` this is giving you a list: try printing what comes out of this, you will see its not what you want ie `for (i in x) print(i)` This is not waht you want:yoo want I to be 1,2,3 thust you need to use `for ( i in seq_along(x))` or `for(i in 1: length(x))` etc... secondly, this will run but will not give you the desired output since your indexing in not correct. With lists we use double brackets to extract the elements and not the single brackets thus you need `x[[i]]`. If possible `unlist(x[[i]])`.